# Compile Java to WebAssembly

Tags: java, llvm, webassembly, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to compile Java to WebAssembly. Is this possible?
My initial approach was to take the example described in [this blog post](https://www.praj.in/posts/2020/graalvms-secret-llvm-backend/)

The approach described in the blog post is as follows:

1. Install [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/) and add native-image and LLVM toolchain to the
   installation
2. Use GraalVM's javac to compile a simple program
   (into a class file)
3. Use GraalVM's native-image program to process
   the class file into a native binary (with options to preprocess
   using llvm)
4. Use the LLVM IR bit code files to compile as WASM binary.

I get to step 4 but after that I can't compile the LLVM IR bit code to wasm.

I get the following error from LLVM:

```
LLVM ERROR: unsupported GC: compressed-pointer
```

Has anyone tried this and succeeded?

Comment: I guess you need to wait for the WASM GC first as mentioned in https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/3391